# object construction [c++]

Tags: c++, constructor

I have this class:

```
class A {
    B b;
    // snip.
}
```

This will work fine as long as B has a constructor which takes no arguments or the default constructor.

However, If B needs to be constructed as B(x), how should the code be modified.
One obvious way is to use new/delete and B* but i am curious about is it possible without using dynamic memory?

Answer (score 6):

Use *member-initialization-list* to initialize the member variables as:

```
class A {
    B b;
    C c;
public:

    A() : b(10){}   //if B's constructor takes int, for example!

    //Or
    A(T x) : b(x), c(x) {} 
         //^^^^^^^^^^^^ this is called member-initialization-list
}
```

Comment: actually its called ctor-initializer or mem-initializer-list when you leave out the :. An initializer-list is often confused with this and is really the part within { } when initializing arrays or aggregates.

Answer (score 2):

`new`/`delete` won't help. You either need a constructor for A ...

```
A::A(X x) : b(x) { }
```

... or use struct initialisation ...

```
A a = { B(x) };
```

Answer (score 2):

Two possibilities :

Either use initialisation list in A's constructor

```
A::A(int x):b(x)
{

}
```

Or, if you can't construct b directly in the constructor of A, you need to have a pointer

```
class A
{
  B * b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> One obvious way is to use new/delete and B* but i am curious about is
>   it possible without using dynamic memory?

Generally you either use a pointer or add one constructor to class B as well so it can pass the argument to initialize object A as many answer has already mentioned.

But in some speical case , you might be able to get away without adding a constructor to class B and without pointer , but via [**value initialization**](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/7995/) when class B doesn't define a constructor:

```
struct B{
int i;
};

struct A{
    B b;
};

int main()
{
    A a ={1}; //here i being initialized to 1
}
```

Please note I don't recommend this value initialization, just so you know that object can be initialized in this way.